# Change buildings color in Google Maps Android SDK (v2)

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm confused with buildings color in Google Maps Android SDK v2. How to change in style buildings color, because for now buildings are always gray?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NhFb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Maps Wizard:
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

And then just find the map and set they style to the XML file

Comment: I just disabled 3D buildings view and this is good solution for me, however I have another question: How to change default bright tiles preloader to own color or image pattern in Google Maps Android SDK for v2 maps?